# Syntax of C++ Template Template Parameters

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

I'm having difficulty understanding the syntax of C++ Template Template parameters. I understand why they are useful, as per the excellent description [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=376878), I just find their syntax hard to get to understand. Two examples taken from the above website (there are others):

```
template <typename T, template <typename> class Cont>
class Stack;
```

and

```
template <template <typename,typename> class Cont>
class Wrapper3;
```

Clearly generalizing such declarations is impossible without some understanding of the rationale behind this syntax. Memorizing is harder and does not seem to be of much help.

Edit:
I realize that my attempt at a question came across like an observation. What I'm asking for is help on how to interprete the Template Template parameter syntax in everyday speak. I can do this with the C++ syntax and the all the other programming languages that I've learned. However I'm having difficulty "explaining" the syntax of C++ Template Template parameters to myself. I've gotten a book, "C++ templates : the complete guide" by David Vandevoorde and Nicolai M. Josuttis, and while its a nice book, it hasn't been of much help to me in understanding this syntax which I'm sure many will agree is at best quirky.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I think he doesn't comprehend the difference between the two template classes

Comment: I understand that both are two different template classes. The problem that I'm having is with the syntax of the Template Template parameters.

Comment: I was just typing out a nice answer... :-(

Comment: @Kerrek: sorry about that :/! However, the question could probably be reopened quite easily with some modifications.

Comment: @Luc I've tried to claifify my question. Please reconsider reopening my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing so arcane about it. Just take out your template template parameters from the original template:

```
template <typename> class Cont
```

Any class template with a single type argument fits, such as

```
template <typename T>
class A {
public:
  A(T t) : t_(t) {}
  T get() { return t_; }
private:
  T t_;
};
```

And you would use your original template as

```
Stack<int, A> s;
```

Answer (score 18):

I am not sure what is your question exactly, but here is the explanation for the two examples you gave.

```
template <typename T, template <typename> class Cont>
class Stack;
```

`Stack` is a class template with two template parameters. The first parameter, `T` can be any type (including built-in types, user-defined types, template instantiations and so on). The second parameter, `Cont`, must be a class template taking one parameter. The parameter is unnamed because it would not make much sense (the parameter is never bound to anything).

```
template <template <typename,typename> class Cont>
class Wrapper3;
```

`Wrapper3` is a class template with a single parameter, `Cont`. `Cont` must be a class template with two parameters.

The syntax to define a template template parameter is the same as the one to define a class template (`template <typename [param1], typename [param2], ...> class Name`), so I don't really understand what is your problem.

However, I agree that the syntax can become a bit awkward when you start "nesting" template template parameters:

```
// class template whose parameter must be a class template whose parameter
// must be a class template
template <template <template <typename> class > class C >
struct Wow {};
```

Doesn't happen that often, though...

Comment: _"The [template template] parameter is unnamed because it would not make much sense (the parameter is never bound to anything)"_. Does this mean `template <template <typename E> class C> class Foo { C<E> myField; }` is not allowed?

Comment: @mucaho You can give a name to the parameter, but you cannot use it, because it is never bound to any type. For instance, assume you have the class `template <typename T> class Bar {}`: you can use it to instantiate `Foo` like this: `Foo<Bar> f`. What is the type represented by E in this case? If you want to write `Foo<Bar<int>>`, then you don't need a template template parameter, just a regular non-template parameter.