# C++ rationale behind Template template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, grammar

This is not a question about template template syntax meaning, but rather a question about why this syntax was chosen by C++ standard committee. Lets take this example,

(1)

```
template< typename T> 
Class A
{
...
}
```

The above one is syntax of a class template syntax with single template argument. I can understand this syntax is something c++ committee can choose arbitrarily.

(2)

```
template<template <typename> typename T>
class B
{
...
}
```

C++ standard committee should have built (2)  syntax using (1) with some language standard/ grammar. I could not understand how (2) was built using (1).

If given a choice I would have chosen the below as template template syntax,

(3)

```
template <typename template< typename T>> //my way of writing syntax (but not recognized by standard)
```

The inner `template<typename T>` in above is a template datatype, so a template of that should be written `template<typename template<typename T>>`

Can anyone explain why the language committee chose (2) instead of (3)

There is a similar question [Syntax of C++ Template Template Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7282971)  which doesn't clarify these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does make sense if you break it down step by step. If we start with a declaration of a templated structure `T`:

```
template <typename U>
struct T;
```

If we have a class `B` which is a template:

```
template <typename T>
struct B;
```

If we replace `typename T` with our declaration above:

```
template <template <typename U> struct T>
struct B;
```

Replace `struct` with `typename`:

```
template <template <typename U> typename T>
struct B;
```

Then we just need to remove the `U` (though you don't have to, you can leave it in, it just has no meaning) and we get:

```
template <template <typename> typename T>
struct B;
```

Your syntax of:

```
template <typename template<typename T>>
```

Would imply that `T` is the type of the parameter of the inner template (`U` in my example) not the outer template type, this would make more sense which isn't too far from the standard:

```
template <typename template<typename> T>
```

Comment: I wouldn't have replaced `T` but `typename T`. That way you don't have a redundant typename to remove which in turn begets the question which of the two to remove.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yeah I was thinking that too

Comment: @AlanBirtles : I like your answer. It answers my question and explains with details. I am confident this will be useful for others. Thanks for your time!